# How to get this one-to-one assoication working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, associations

I've created a one-to-one association between my Admin and Report models and it isn't working just yet. I'm using `Devise` to log in via an Admin model so in the controller I'm using the current_admin helper. Silly question, but what migration do I need to run to get this working?

**Error**

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  column reports.admin_id does not exist
2011-10-14T09:16:57+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT  "reports".* FROM "reports" WHERE ("reports".admin_id = ...
```

**Report model**

```
belongs_to :admin, :foreign_key => "admin_id"
```

**Admin model**

```
has_one :report, :foreign_key => "admin_id"
```

**Controller**

```
@report = current_admin.report
```

**Schema**

```
create_table "reports", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "description"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "user_id"
end

create_table "admins", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "email",                                 :default => "", :null => false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     :limit => 128, :default => "", :null => false
  t.string   "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",                         :default => 0
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `admin_id` in `reports`. You can remove the `foreign_key` stuff in your models. That's done automatically. Create a migration, add

```
add_column :reports, :admin_id, :integer
```

Run `rake db:migrate` and you're done.